# Bee: 0001 Command is missing

Tags: go, beego

i am using Bee tool, Beego version `v2.0.2`, i want to create `routerComment` file using `bee generate routers` but got error `"0001 Command is missing"`, other commands are working fine. How can i fix this error?

Comment: please post the command that you are running and output that you are getting while running the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go install github.com/beego/bee/v2@develop